# Is there a particular structure that a research lab should have?

Tags: phd, research-process, lab-management

I want to know if a research lab at a university should normally include specific roles in order to be considered a lab ?
I explain, for a newly joining Ph.D. student, i expect the lab to include a post-doc and at least other Ph.Ds, is it reasonable expectations ?

Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: Why "should"? Do you think it impossible to work without some specific structure?

Comment: i expect at least to find a postdoc to help with the work

Comment: So, if a lab doesn't have a postdoc then it isn't a lab? Postdocs aren't there to "help". They are there to advance their research interests for the most part.

Comment: i seen good labs only with : PhDs and at least one postdoc, could also include MS .. but mostly what i am saying postdocs will play the role of teamleads, because the advisor won't

Comment: I suspect you've "seen" only a small subset of what exists.

Comment: not exactly especially when it comes to team members

Comment: @marcnicole I think these are personal preferences imo! However, there's not a "for all" structure. However, if you're putting a perspective on whether the workflow should have a structure, that's a different matter though!

Comment: Varies greatly by field. Biology, mathematics, engineering, medical research, ...

Comment: A lab: just me in my office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, this is very dependent on the nature of research. I'll share some trends that are common to many engineering research labs. The commonality derives from the following:

1. At least some of the equipment is specialized and high-end,
   requiring extensive training to be used. This means that senior PhD
   or post-docs are generally tasked with transferring skills to new
   students.
2. Some part of the research is directed towards
   building/improving/expanding machines or processes. So some students
   build skills in a specific subsystem over the PhD, and often future
   students work on extensions of the same. If so, you may find within
   the lab some students focusing on (for example) developing
   instrumentation, others on finding new uses for it, and so on.
3. The turnaround time for PhDs is often limited by grants/funding,
   so its necessary to keep things moving. That can happen when
   knowledge and skills are continually passed down across student
   generations.

In such a setting, each PhD student, over their tenure, would typically mentor 2-3 generations of students (doctoral or masters) and meet two post-docs (since they usually stay for shorter periods). The post-docs may not have any academic/technical overlap with many students since they are working in very specialized areas. It is therefore not a great idea to think of post-docs as being there (or being able!) to help fresh students. Ideally, once the lab is established, other PhD students will partially shoulder that responsibility.

Answer (score 5):

No, there are no standards for what is considered a "lab."

I know of labs with many postdocs, lots of staff, and few students. I know of other labs that are more focused on undergrads, with a few grad students and no postdocs.

Of course, you can take the lab composition into account when deciding whether it is a good fit, but there is no criterion to point to and say "ah, this is a poorly structured lab."

Answer (score 3):

If the lab is small(ish), there just won't be that many people around to assign a lot of roles. How it is structured is quite irrelevant, what is important is (a) the results it puts out, and (b) (probably more important to you) do the people participating there get their degrees in a timely manner, with good results (publications).

I've seen labs that had a few master's students (working on their theses), a bunch of undergraduate students (on their theses or preparing for them) and some interested undergraduates hanging on. There was no PhD program here in that time frame,

Comment: quite irrelevant for who ? for the student definitely no